# How to re-render componet when Promise value changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

could you please help me to solve the problem connected with Vue component re-rendering. I'm getting the data via consuming a Promise. Once the data is available under the specific property chain (visualData.layout.cube...), I'm assigning a value to a DATA properties (label, indicatorValue...).

Unfortunately, component has no re-render option when the data under Promise changes (e.g. when using application filters or clicking on some charts or whatever). Component data changes just when I switch between the routes or do the page reload.

What is the Vue solution to watch for the changes coming from the Promise?

```
data() {
    return {
        label: null,
        indicatorState: null,
        indicatorValue: null,
    }
},
computed: {
  isAppReady() {
    return this.$store.getters.isAppReady;
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.$store.watch(() => this.isAppReady, (status) => {
    if (status) { // if STATUS === true
      this.getData();
    }
  });

  if (this.isAppReady) {
    this.getData();
  }
},
methods: {
  getData() {
    return this.appMethods // global object gathering specific methods like .getObject, .getField etc.
      .getObject(null, this.visualID)
      .then(visualData => visualData.layout.cube.dataPages[0].matrix[0])
      .then((transformedData) => {
        this.label = transformedData[0].qText;
        this.indicatorValue = transformedData[1].qText;
        this.indicatorState = Number(transformedData[1].qNum) > 0;
      });
  },
},
```

Comment: If you re-ran `getData`, then the data properties should be updated. It's not clear what your problem is

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to check if Promise finishes. Your code does update the data in getData(), the problem may be caused by your template doesn't bind the data properties correctly.

Comment: @Phil, the problem is that I cannot simply re-ran getData method, because I have no buttons, handlers etc. where such method can be invoked.

I'm looking for the solution, which will listen for the changes which currently resolve my Promise and then immediately assign those changes to the Data property to show the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Vuex, I would separate data fetching from the component,

- move the `getData()` method to a service
- call it in the click handler of any component where you wish to invoke a refresh
- push fresh data to the store
- access the properties from the store

Service code

```js
getData() {
  return this.appMethods 
    .getObject(null, this.visualID)
    .then(visualData => visualData.layout.cube.dataPages[0].matrix[0])
    .then((transformedData) => {
      this.$store.commit('SET_MY_DATA', transformedData);
    });
}
```

Watch it via computed's in the component

```js
computed: {
  label() {
    return this.$store.getters.label
  } 
  indicatorState() {
    return this.$store.getters.indicatorState
  } 
  indicatorValue() {
    return this.$store.getters.indicatorValue
  } 
},
```

Comment: your solution is ok when you have a place to invoke the service method. I don't have such place - I need to constantly listen to  .getObject response changes and that's my challenge. What is the way to solve my issue ?

Comment: First thing is (I think @Phil mentioned it), a Promise does not continuously fire. Does `this.appMethods.getObject()` return a Promise or an Observable? If a Promise, it only resolves once.

Comment: Second thing, you say **when using application filters or clicking on some charts or whatever** - the clicking on the chart needs a click handler, which should then call `getData()` from within the service. **Application filters** - a bit vague, but presume the user chooses a filter - again a handler for that user action will call `getData()`.

Comment: Yes, but the Charts / Visuals + Filters come from the 3rd party BI tool, so I have no access to overwrite the HTML structure and/or add my own handler to be invoked. It's more than complicated I would say.